# Geopandas: How to associate a Point to a Linestring using the original Linestring order

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

Using Geopandas, Shapely

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
street = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'street': ['st'], 'geometry': LineString([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)])})
pp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [Point((1.9, 1.9)), Point((1.5, 1.5)), Point((2.5, 1.5)), Point((1.2, 1.2))]})
print(street)
print(pp)
```

Suppose I have a Linestring that represents a (cornered) street:

LineString([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)])

Note that the order of points in this linestring matters because LineString([(1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2)]) would represent a very different street.

Now, suppose I have list of points that **belong** to my street:

Point((1.9, 1.9))

Point((1.5, 1.5))

Point((2.5, 1.5))

Point((1.2, 1.2))

I want to create a new Linestring where all the Points are "merged" with the original street coordinates. This "merge" mechanism has to maintain the original street shape as follows:

LineString([**(1, 1)**, (1.2, 1.2), (1.5, 1.5), (1.9, 1.9), **(2, 2)**, (2.5, 1.5). **(3, 1)**])

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: This question was properly answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413737/geopandas-how-to-associate-a-point-to-a-linestring-using-the-original-linestrin

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:**

> I wouldn't know there's an existing function to do that. It seems as your challenge is to identify the segment of the street where you have to add a point. You can calculate the linear distance of the point to each segment. The segment with the min distance is the one you have to add it to ... btw all shapely object have the distance method already implemented

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).